# Two Iframes are communicating: SecurityError

Tags: javascript, iframe

I have two iframes. These iframes are communicating together through `postMessage`.

**From one iframe, if I do the following it doesn't work.**

```
// Broadcast to all iframes.
parent.frames.forEach(function (frame) {
  frame.postMessage(data, 'http://localhost:4000');
});
```

**Error**:

> Uncaught SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin "http://..." from accessing a frame with origin "http://...". Protocols, domains, and ports must match.

**However, if I do the following, it works very well. No error message. Why?**

```
for (var i = 0 ; i < parent.frames.length ; ++i) {
  parent.frames[i].postMessage(data, 'http://localhost:4000');
}
```

Comment: The question here looks like it can be read as "Why does `parent.frames.forEach` give a _SecurityError_ when I can iterate over them in a `for`?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question here looks like it can be read as

> Why does `parent.frames.forEach` give a *SecurityError* when I can iterate over them in a `for`?

This is because `parent.frames` is **not an *Array*** but a *Window* instance and therefore, when you try to access `.forEach`, it's looking for a property on a different *Window* which the security prevents access to.

From the MDN page of [`window.frames`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.frames) (`parent` is a *Window*)

> **Returns the window itself**, which is an **array-like** object, listing the direct sub-frames of the current window.

If you want to use `.forEach`, take it from (a referencabe) *Array's* prototype

```
Array.prototype.forEach.call(parent.frames, callback);
```